# Best way to sort estates and query them (for rent? yes/no. contains office space? yes/no)?

Tags: custom-field, taxonomy, query, meta-query

I´m building a real estate site where Estates is a custom post type. I want to be able to tick a checkbox or something similare on the edit page, where I can choose if the estate is for rent, if it contains office space etc. And then be able to query against this in different templates.

I´m wondering what´s the best way to achive this. I´m using 'Advanced Custom Fields' to type in a lot of information about the estates and that is working well. I thought I could just use a custom field checkbox for this aswell but it seems you can´t query against a custom field value if the values are in an array.

Should I be using taxonomies instead? I could do that, but it makes less sense for the user and I don´t want them to be able to add terms, which they can.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are your custom field values saved as an array? Why don't you create separate custom field for every property "feature" - you will then be able to use meta_query when querying posts.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly use the Advanced Fields plugin for this type of functionality - you'll just need to add a few lines to the query that creates your custom pages. I found the [documentation on checkboxes](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/field-types/checkbox/) from ACF to be helpful. Scroll through the code examples at the bottom of the page and you'll see this:

```
/*
 * Query posts for a checkbox value.
 * This method uses the meta_query LIKE to match the string "red" to 
 * the database value a:2:{i:0;s:3:"red";i:1;s:4:"blue";} (serialized array)
 * The above value suggests that the user selected "red" and "blue" from 
 * the checkbox choices
 */
 $posts = get_posts(array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'field_name', // name of custom field
            'value' => '"red"', // matches exaclty "red", 
                //not just red. This prevents a match for "acquired"
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
));

if( $posts )
{
    //...
}
```

You can modify this code to work with a [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) as well.